# EWS: How can I know who created a meeting in the conference rooms calendar directly?

Tags: powershell-2.0, exchangewebservices

When an user creates a meeting directly in the calendar of a conference room, the organizer field is set as the room's name(Not has the user who has created the meeting).
Is it possible to get the name of the user who has created the meeting using EWS 2010?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Sender Extended properties that should show the creators name (while send on behalf would be the Mailbox name) e.g.

```c
Mailbox MeetingRoom = new Mailbox("room@domain.com");
FindItemsResults<Appointment> appts = service.FindAppointments(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar,MeetingRoom),new CalendarView(DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),1000));
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0C1F,MapiPropertyType.String);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE_W = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0C1E,MapiPropertyType.String);
PropertySet psProps = new PropertySet();
psProps.Add(PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE_W);
psProps.Add(PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W);
if(appts.Items.Count > 0){
    service.LoadPropertiesForItems(from Item item in appts select item,psProps);
    foreach(Appointment apt in appts){
        Object SenderAddressType = null;
        Object SenderAddress = null;
        if(apt.TryGetProperty(PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE_W,out SenderAddressType)){
            if(apt.TryGetProperty(PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W,out SenderAddress)){
                if(SenderAddressType.ToString() == "EX")
                {
                    NameResolutionCollection nccol = service.ResolveName(SenderAddress.ToString(),ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,true);
                    if(nccol.Count == 1){
                        Console.WriteLine(nccol[0].Mailbox.Address);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(SenderAddress);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```